# Could anyone provide an example of valid configuration of traefik as an internal loadbalancer on AWS ECS&

Tags: amazon-ecs, traefik

I'm new to traefik and I need to configure it as an internal loadbalancer and reverse proxy for services in AWS ECS on EC2. I couldn't find an example of a traefik task definition or service definition for AWS ECS on EC2. Can anyone please provide an example of how it can be done because official documentation for ecs on traefik website is not very clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In you `docker labels` you can add the `key` `value` pairs

[image]

Comment: Should I add these lables in traefik task definition or in every service task definition or in both?

Comment: Every Service task definition

Comment: Do let me know if this helped you.